# crear un archivo json en Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Quiero crear un archivo json y guardarlo en una ruta x, abajo el código que estoy ocupando.

```
import json
import os
ruta = {}
ruta['nombre']= 'Jose'
ruta['edad']='15'
ruta['nacionalidad']='Mex'
carpeta = 'C:%sPruebas' % os.sep
os.chdir(carpeta) #esta es la linea que hace que se cambie el lugar de trabajo
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    carpeta = 'C:%sPruebas' % os.sep
    archivo = json.dump(ruta,outfile)
```

Answer (score 2):

Estas guardando el archivo en el directorio de trabajo actual, si quieres guardarlo en "*C:\Pruebas*" debes pasar la ruta a `open`. Para crear tu ruta te recomiendo usar `os.path.join` en vez de concatenar/formatear cadenas:

```
import json
import os

data = {}
data['nombre'] = 'Jose'
data['edad'] = '15'
data['nacionalidad'] = 'Mex'

dir = 'C:/Pruebas'  # También es válido 'C:\\Pruebas' o r'C:\Pruebas'
file_name = "data.json"

with open(os.path.join(dir, file_name), 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data, file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya que indicas que usas python 3.6, te voy a hacer algunas recomendaciones para hacer más *pythónico* el código:

- En lugar de usar el operador formato `'%'`, se recomienda usar las [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) o *"literales de formato"*.
- En lugar de contruirte las rutas de ficheros, se recomienda usar el módulo [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html) e intentar que tu código sirva para cualquier plataforma, aunque estés trabajando en windows.

Por lo que parece, quieres que tu fichero json se guarde en `C:\Pruebas`, una ruta que sólo existe en windows. Por tanto se debe usar `pathlib.WindowsPath` de esta manera:

```
from pathlib import WindowsPath

dir = WindowsPath('C:\Pruebas')
fichero = dir / "data.json"

with fichero.open("w") as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```

Como no tendría mucho texto, la escritura puede ser más directa:

```
fichero.write_text(json.dumps(data), encoding="utf8")
```

Comment: ¿A qué se debe `fichero = dir / "data.json"`? Entiendo que quieres concatenar esos valores.

Comment: Así es, pero concatenado con el separador para rutas. Equivalente a `os.path.join(r"C:\Pruebas", "data.json")`, equivalente (más o menos) a lo que se quería hacer con `'C:%sPruebas' % os.sep`.

Comment: Ah qué bueno, no sabía que se pudiera utilizar `/` en este contexto para generar rutas en Windows. ¡Resulta utilísimo!

Comment: Es una de las cosas de python3 que no se usan por desidia. Dejo un [artículo](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f) con algunos trucos de este módulo.