# Cómo generar archivos json en python?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio

Necesito a partir de este código implementar una opción del menú principal que genere en un archivo JSON el resultado de consultar los estudiantes de un determinado grado, incluyendo los datos básicos de cada estudiante. Una opción del menú principal que lea y presente en pantalla la información contenida en el archivo JSON de lo anterior e implementar el manejo de errores y excepciones para evitar errores e interrupciones en la ejecución del programa.
Esos códigos ya los creé pero no sé como hacer lo otro. Ayudaaa

```
    import os
import funciones as f
os.system('cls')


def main():
    estudiantes = f.registro_estudiantes()
    print()

    op = 1
    while op !=0:
        print("MENÚ PRINCIPAL")
        print("0) Salir")
        print("1) Registrar estudiante")
        print("2) Ver informacion de los estudiantes registrados")
        print("3) Consultar y actualizar la información básica de un estudiante en particular")
        print("4) Consultar y eliminar toda la información relacionada con un estudiante en particular")
        print("5) Calcular valor de matricula")

        op = int(input("Digite la opción deseada: "))

        if op == 1:
            estudiantes = f.registrar_nuevo_estudiante(estudiantes)
        elif op == 2 or op == 5:
            f.ver_informacion_estudiantes(estudiantes,op)
            
        elif op == 3:
            f.actualizar_estudiante(estudiantes)
        elif op == 4:
            f.eliminar_estudiante(estudiantes)
main()
```

Tengo las funciones en el sgte archivo

```
def registro_estudiantes():
    estudiantes = list()
    N = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad inicial de estudiantes que desea registrar: "))
    for i in range(N):
        print("Estudiante",i+1)
        documento = int(input("Ingrese el documento del estudiante: "))
        nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: ")
        estrato = int(input("Ingrese el estrato del estudiante: "))

        grado = int(input("Ingrese el grado a matricular: "))
        promedio = float(input("Ingrese el promedio ponderado del estudiante: "))
        estudiantes.append({'documento':documento,'nombre':nombre,'estrato':estrato,'grado':grado,'promedio':promedio})
    return estudiantes

def registrar_nuevo_estudiante(estudiantes):
    documento = int(input("Ingrese el documento del estudiante: "))
    nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: ")
    estrato = int(input("Ingrese el estrato del estudiante: "))

    grado = int(input("Ingrese el grado a matricular: "))
    promedio = float(input("Ingrese el promedio ponderado del estudiante: "))
    estudiantes.append({'documento':documento,'nombre':nombre,'estrato':estrato,'grado':grado,'promedio':promedio})
    return estudiantes


def valor_descuento(estudiante,gasto_papeleria):
    if estudiante['promedio'] >= 4.5:#si tiene descuento se aplica, sino devuelve lo mismo
        gasto_papeleria = gasto_papeleria/2
    return gasto_papeleria


def gasto_papeleria(estudiante):
    gasto_papeleria = 0                  
    if estudiante['estrato'] == 1:
        gasto_papeleria = 25000
    elif estudiante['estrato'] == 2:
        gasto_papeleria = 40000
    elif estudiante['estrato'] == 3:
        gasto_papeleria = 60000
    
    return valor_descuento(estudiante,gasto_papeleria)

def valor_apf(estudiante):
    apf = 0
    if estudiante['estrato'] == 1:
        apf = 10000
    elif estudiante['estrato'] == 2:
        apf = 15000
    elif estudiante['estrato'] == 3:
        apf = 15000
    return apf


def valor_practica(estudiante):
    practicas = 0
    if estudiante['grado'] == 11 or estudiante['grado'] == 10:
        practicas = 30000
    return practicas
    
def valor_final_matricula(estudiante):
    return valor_apf(estudiante)+valor_practica(estudiante)+gasto_papeleria(estudiante)

def ver_informacion_estudiantes(estudiantes,op):
    for i in range(len(estudiantes)):
        print("Estudiante",i+1)
        print("Documento:",estudiantes[i]['documento'])
        print("Nombre:",estudiantes[i]['nombre'])
        print("Estrato:",estudiantes[i]['estrato'])
        print("Grado:",estudiantes[i]['grado'])
        print("Promedio:",estudiantes[i]['promedio'])
        if(op == 5):
            print("Gasto papeleria",gasto_papeleria(estudiantes[i]))
            print("Asoc Padres de Familia", valor_apf(estudiantes[i]))
            print("Practicas", valor_practica(estudiantes[i]))
            print("Valor final a pagar:",gasto_papeleria(estudiantes[i])+valor_apf(estudiantes[i])+valor_practica(estudiantes[i]))

    if len(estudiantes)==0:
            print("No hay estudiantes registrados")



#escritura json
with open('estudiantes.json','w') as archivo:
    json.dump(estudiantes, archivo)
    print("Archivo exportado")

#lectura json
"""
with open('estudiantes.json','r') as archivo:
    estudiantes= json.load(archivo)
    print("Archivo obtenido con éxito!!")
    
print(estudiantes)



def actualizar_estudiante(estudiantes):
    id = int(input("Ingrese el documento del estudiante a modificar: "))
    for i in range(len(estudiantes)):
        if estudiantes[i]['documento'] == id:
            estudiantes[i]['documento'] = int(input("Ingrese el documento del estudiante: "))
            estudiantes[i]['nombre'] = input("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: ")
            estudiantes[i]['estrato'] = int(input("Ingrese el estrato del estudiante: "))
            estudiantes[i]['grado'] = int(input("Ingrese el grado a matricular: "))
            estudiantes[i]['promedio'] = float(input("Ingrese el promedio ponderado del estudiante: "))
            print("Actualizado exitosamente")
            break

def eliminar_estudiante(estudiantes):
    id = int(input("Ingrese el documento del estudiante a eliminar: "))
    for i in range(len(estudiantes)):
        if estudiantes[i]['documento'] == id:
            estudiantes.pop(i)
            print("Eliminado exitosamente!!")
            break
```

Comment: Te sirve el modulo [json](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/json.html)?

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta concreta? ¿Cómo generar JSON? Hay cientos de tutoriales (en castellano) que te lo enseñaran. ¿Ninguno de ellos te sirvio?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [crear un archivo json en Python 3.6.1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137013/crear-un-archivo-json-en-python-3-6-1)

Comment: He creado de esta manera un archivo 
#escritura json
with open('informacion_estudiante.json','w') as archivo:
    json.dump(informacion_estudiante, archivo)
    print("Archivo exportado")


#lectura json
"""
with open('informacion_estudiante.json','r') as archivo:
    informacion_estudiante= json.load(archivo)
    print("Archivo obtenido con éxito!!")
    
print(informacion_estudiante)

Pero al modificarlo y meterlo al código no me funciona

Comment: Podrías agregar ese código en la pregunta por favor? En los comentarios no se bien dicho. Gracias por agregar esa información c:

Comment: Listo ya lo añadí

Comment: Osea no tienes ni idea de como generar el json con todos los resultados?

Comment: No, no sé como generar el archivo de acuerdo a la opción